# GitLab CE 14.10: изменение git_data_dirs

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner, ci-cd, centos8

Я использую Gitlab ce 14.10 на CentOS 8. В связи с нехваткой места в `/var` решил переместить и изменить место хранения репозиториев согласно документации. Репо перемещены через rsync, конфиг изменен:

```
git_data_dirs({
  "default" => {
    "path" => "/data/gitlab/git-data"
   }
})
```

После рестарта выявлены баги:

1. Не всегда срабатывает триггер на запуск раннера (иногда gitlab как будто не видит `gitlab-ci.yml`)
2. При выставлении параметра удаления ветки в mr после успешного принятия mr ветка не удаляется

После некоторого количества неудачных попыток разобраться с этим я вернул репо назад и решил просто добавить новое хранилище как дополнительное:

```
git_data_dirs({
  "default" => {
    "path" => "/var/opt/gitlab/git-data"
   },
  "storage1" => {
    "path" => "/data/gitlab/git-data"
   }
})
```

В результате для репо созданных в новом хранилище:

1. CI/CD вообще не срабатывает
2. При mr постоянно крутиться проверка возможности mr и до конца не доходит. Помогает только закрытие mr.

Перепробовал очистки кэшей и прочее что нашел в гугле. Сверял права доступов к папкам в `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data` и `/data/gitlab/git-data` - все одинаковое.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: ¿`reconfigure` не выполнялось?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. После перемещения всех текущих репо в /data/git-data, вручную поставил права к директориям:

- /data/git-data - 0700 git:git
- /data/git-data/repositories - 2770 git:git

После reconfigure в панели администратора принудительно запустил все фоновые задания Sidekiq и дождался их завершения.